# Having trouble with Java MemorySegment

Tags: java

I'm using Java 17.0.6, and trying to work with `MemorySegment`. The code is like:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pathString);
FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
long totalSize = fileChannel.size();
ResourceScope resourceScope = ResourceScope.newConfinedScope();
MemorySegment memorySegment = MemorySegment.mapFile(Path.of(pathString), 0, totalSize, FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, resourceScope);
float f = MemoryAccess.getFloatAtOffset(memorySegment, 3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024L);
System.out.println(f);
```

The file I'm trying to read is bigger than 10GB.

When I run the code, I got error like:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff929c14e18, pid=9304, tid=9920
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.6+9) (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.6+9-LTS-190, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x7a4e18]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
```

Is this a bug of Java?

Comment: `3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024L` is less than 10GB.

Comment: How much memory did you assign to the JVM when you started it up (via the _java_ command)? I very much doubt that the default amount is sufficient. Refer to the documentation for the [java command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html).

Comment: Don’t use MemorySegment unless you are interacting with native libraries.  Just use [FileChannel.map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,long,long)).  For example, `float f = FileChannel.open(Path.of(pathString)).map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024L, Float.BYTES).getFloat();`

Comment: @VGR FileChannel.map maybe not big enough. There is a 2G limit.

Comment: Yes, but I’m guessing you don’t have to map the entire file all at once.